# Intellisense not working for C/C++ in Visual Studio code

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code

So I have C/C++ by Microsoft extension installed but where auto suggestions and code-completions for other languages seem to be working perfectly,I am facing problem with C/C++

As I create a new file in C,there seem to be no autosuggestion.Even pressing `ctrl + space` says "no suggestions"

I have `code runner` extension installed.So what seems to be the problem?

Comment: Are you sure you only have one instance of Visual Studio running? When you have two of them, the Intellisense stops working.

Answer (score 0):

- Is Autocomplete enabled?
- What is your Intelli Sense Mode?
- Your System Include Path set correctly?
- What is your Intelli Sense Engine?
- Your Intelli Sense Engine Fallback?
- last but not least: is there something to suggest?

I do not use code runner but is far i have seen, there too, are some paths to set, although i don't how they're related to each other.